# Why does native Android datepicker have different styles on Personal vs Work

Tags: android, datepicker

I'm using `@react-native-community/datetimepicker` pretty much out of the box. I noticed if the app is downloaded on the Personal tab of an Android device, the calendar picker is blue, and has blue buttons at the bottom. If it's downloaded on the Work tab, it's green, and the buttons at the bottom are white text, causing it to appear as if there are no buttons. What is this about?

This is the the exact same device:

Personal profile:

[image: personal profile]

Work profile:

[image: work profile]

Comment: Does this only happen on Android 12 devices? I could only imagine that the Material You color system might break something.

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann this is an Android 12 device. I'll test on others to confirm if it's only Android 12

Comment: Did you test it? I am curious.